# SQL server result has a hyphen but it's not showing elsewhere

Tags: sql-server

Have a strange case of hyphens that are not showing correctly in an app, but they are in the database.

On the front end of the app there is only one hyphen that shows like below,

```
12 someText 23 otherText 4-5
```

When I query the data from SQL server the results window shows this,

```
1-2 someText 2-3 otherText 4--5
```

But if I copy and paste the text from the results it looks like it does in the app.

This was not entered by me though, I tried to replicate this from my own tests. But whether from the front end, insert or updating straight from SQL Server it shows fine for me. My only thought was that there may be a special character programmed to the users keyboard that we don't support, and they think it is a hyphen.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: what happens when you return use `results to text` (ctrl+t) instead of `results to grid` (ctrl+d) in sql server management studio?

Comment: is the data type in the database `varchar` or `nvarchar` or something else?

Comment: Are you using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to query the database or something else?

Comment: @SqlZim I'm using grid, because with the text the filed gets cut off as it's a large string. The field is Varchar (max)

Comment: @jim31415 I am using SSMS

Comment: I think the -- is getting turned into a hyphen. This is often the case in MS Word and other similar applications. It automatically translates two dashes as a hyphen... aka "long dash". If you copy the results from SSMS into NOTEPAD or Notepad++ you should see both dashes. Word or another text editor could change it

Comment: @scsimon I think it's just some weird characters a user might have on their keyboard. If I pasted it into SSMS or notepad it goes away. But with notepad++ it showed fine. I when I updated the field this weirdness went away.